# How to get name from social security number (inside link)

Tags: mysql, sql

I have situation where table is named PERSON and there are these columns:

- SOCSECNUM (Sosial security number)
- FIRSTNAME
- LASTNAME
- MANAGER

There is employees and managers. Employees have manager and manager "value" is shown as social security number. Managers does not have manager so their manager value is null.

With this i can see the names of employees and their manager social security numbers (where manager column is not null):

```
SELECT LASTNAME + ', ' + FIRSTNAME AS NAME_OF_EMPLOYEE,
MANAGER AS MANAGER_SOCIAL_SECURITY_NUMBER

FROM PERSON

WHERE MANAGER IS NOT NULL
```

I want get name of the manager (`SOCSECNUM`). All persons have first name, last name and social security number. I have to link them somehow, but i don't know how. I hope you understand what i mean :)

Comment: Help us help you - please share some sample data and the result you're trying to get for it

Comment: If that code works, you are not using MySQL.  Tag with the database you are really using.

Comment: @Gordon Linoff I just started stuidying this. I don't know what database that is. Our teacher has done it for us and it works only in our school network or via school VPN, so i can't link it here. I was also wondering why you are using ```()``` and ```;```. Maybe those are coming later for us :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Storing unencrypted social security numbers to represent employees pretty much violates every precept of privacy that I know.  Even in countries where this may not be protected, I would strongly advise using an artificial key for these tables.

That said, you seem to simply want a `join`:

```
SELECT (p.LASTNAME + ', ' + p.FIRSTNAME) AS NAME_OF_EMPLOYEE,
       (pm.LASTNAME + ', ' + pm.FIRSTNAME) AS NAME_OF_MANAGER
FROM PERSON p JOIN
     PERSON pm
     ON pm.SOCSECNUM = p.MANAGER;
```

Comment: Thanks! I can do cross linking and few tables together, but inside linking was little problem to me but not anymore :)

Comment: I miss one important thing of this case. Those managers are also employess of company and they must be on list of employees.

In my first message that code return all employees if I delete ```WHERE MANAGER IS NOT NULL```. So, then I have 12 rows, all employees icncluding three managers. I tried different joins and always there is only 9 employees (without manager names) or more than 12 (somehow multiplied them).

Comment: @masteroscar . . . The `JOIN` filters out rows where `MANAGER` is `NULL`.  If you replace `JOIN` with `LEFT JOIN` you should get the original rows in the table -- unless you have duplicates (i.e. two rows with the same `SOCSECNUM`).

Comment: Thanks Gordon, it is working now correctly! I must read more about that ```LEFT JOIN``` how it works.